# curandGenerateNormalDouble is crashing with larege number of random numbers to be generated

Tags: random, cuda, generator

Is there any limitation of the

curandGenerateNormal(
curandGenerator_t generator,
float *outputPtr, size_t n,
float mean, float stddev)

function?
curandGenerateNormal is called inside a loop, when I increase the size of the **size_t n** parameter, the code started to crash when it has been called a few times.

Any ideas?

Comment: The GenerateUniformDouble function runs okey inside the loop but we need curandGenerateNormalDouble to produce the number between 0 and 1.

Please help.

Comment: "curandGenerateNormalDouble is crashing with"... with what?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate on what actually happens when it crashes? Do you check all the error values?

Your loop should look something like the code below. Is it possible that the cudaMalloc is failing without your knowledge and hence you are passing an invalid pointer, or something similar?

```
curandGenerator_t gen;
curandResult = curandCreateGenerator(&gen, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT));
if (curandResult != CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    // throw or whatever
}

curandResult = curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen, 1234ULL));
if (curandResult != CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    // throw or whatever
}

cudaResult = cudaMalloc((void **)&data, szend * sizeof(float));
if (cudaResult != cudaSuccess)
{
    // throw or whatever
}

for (unsigned int sz = szstart ; sz <= szend ; sz += szstep)
{
    float *data = 0;

    /* Could allocate and free the memory on each iteration,
       instead of allocating for the maximum size upfront...
    cudaResult = cudaMalloc((void **)&data, sz * sizeof(float));
    if (cudaResult != cudaSuccess)
    {
        // throw or whatever
    }
    */
    curandResult = curandGenerateNormal(gen, data, sz, mean, stddev);
    if (curandResult != CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        // throw or whatever
    }
    /* If allocating on each iteration, need to free...
    cudaResult = cudaFree(data);
    if (cudaResult != cudaSuccess)
    {
        // throw or whatever
    }
    */
}
cudaResult = cudaFree(data);
if (cudaResult != cudaSuccess)
{
    // throw or whatever
}

curandResult = curandDestroyGenerator(&gen));
if (curandResult != CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    // throw or whatever
}
```

With regard to your comment, note that curandGenerateNormalDouble will generate Normally distributed numbers with a given mean and standard deviation, that conflicts with your requirement that they be between 0 and 1. What distribution do you need?

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the reply. we need random numbers from NormalDistribution with mean 0 and stddev 1. The crashing I got is from the loop when the sz paramter value is large. Also, when the curandResult != CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS, how could we output some detailed error messages. Thanks

Comment: For allocating and free the memory on each iteration, will that slow down the performance? I am allocating the memory before the loop start with a fixed size equal to the number of random numbers generated in each loop and free the memory after the loop. However, when the number of random numbers needs to be generated is huge, the program crash after a few runs with curandGenerateNormalDouble.

Comment: I used #define CURAND_CALL(x) do { if((x) != CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS) { \
 printf("%s Error at %s:%d\n", "CURAND Library", __FILE__,__LINE__);\
 return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0) from the API samples when calling the curandGenerateNormalDouble so the program stopped when the renturn value is not equal to CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS.

Comment: In this line curandResult = curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen, 1234ULL)); What does ULL after the 1234 for? thanks

Comment: I also tried the sample code above. When the curandGenerateNormal(gen, data, sz, mean, stddev) has a bigger value of sz, e.g. 250000, the code will crash after a few calls through the loop.